# Changing DOM in batch is not faster than changing DOM one by one

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, createelement, virtual-dom

I know that changing DOM in a batch is faster than changing DOM one by one.

And this is the concept of Virtual DOM.

The problem is the example that I made.

In this example, I wanna show changing DOM in a batch is faster.

So I compared change DOM in a batch with doing this one by one.

But there is no difference.

sometimes changing DOM one by one is even faster.

If anyone know what problem is in the code.

please let me know.

here is the code.
https://codepen.io/welinhong/pen/pooypvd

1. one by one

```
function changeDom() {
  const start = performance.now()
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    const el = document.createElement('div')
    el.innerText = `${i}`
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(el)
  }
  const end = performance.now()
  document.getElementById('time').innerText = `${end - start}ms`
}
```

2. in a batch

```
function changeDomInBatch() {
  const start = performance.now()
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    const el = document.createElement('div')
    el.innerText = `${i}`
    fragment.appendChild(el)
  }
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(fragment)
  const end = performance.now()
  document.getElementById('time').innerText = `${end - start}ms`
}
```

Comment: JSPerf for testing purposes: https://jsperf.com/dom-batch-vs-1-by-1